# Oracle lock table while updating it

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle table that is used by downstream systems. Whenever I am making changes to the table (DML), I want to prevent the downstream system from reading it.

Is it possible to do in Oracle? From what I read, even if I lock the table while updating it, readers can still query the table. 
Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: You can't prevent readers from reading the table. But it is not a problem, because readers don't see any uncommited change, just make all changes within a single transaction, and commit the transaction at the end. Before you commit, readers will see the previous version of the data, will not see any changed data.

Comment: You can make them use a view on that table instead, and before you run updates, change the view where clause to "where 1=0". This way they will only see a blank single row.

Comment: @access_granted A much less invasive way to do that is to use `DBMS_RLS` to attach a policy to the table that enforces the `WHERE 1=0` rule.  Also, with `DBMS_RLS` you have the flexibility to make the policy apply _only_ to the downstream systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Oracle Fine Grained Auditing feature to create a policy that will raise an ORA-20001 "Table XYZ is currently undergoing maintenance, please try again later" whenever someone attempts to access the table via a `SELECT` statement.

As an added bonus, you can limit the policy to affect only `SELECT` statements requesting the rows or columns being updated (if you know them).  For example, suppose you have a process that updates only a few columns.  Your FGA policy can be configured to only throw the ORA-20001 when any of those columns is requested -- leaving the table available for queries unrelated to your processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SYNONYM (but I did not try this before)

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(col1 VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TABLE t2
(col1 VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO t1
values ('t1');

CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM TABLE1_S FOR T1;

SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE1_S;

COL1     
----------
t1     

CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM TABLE1_S FOR T2;

SELECT * FROM TABLE1_S;

no rows selected
```